# How can I get rid of overflow on my responsive navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my navbar. I'm using Bootstrap for a responsive navbar but it overflows on the mobile version of my site. I used overflow-x: hidden on body and it solved the problem for larger versions but not the mobile version. I've checked for margin/padding issues on all my elements in the navbar but can't seem to find the problem. You can see the issue on www.tcbarringerphotography.com on the right hand side if you view it smaller than 500ish pixels. Any ideas?

Comment: hi welcome to stack overflow, please provide more information such as screenshot to your problem, ideally you could make the [mre] via js fiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with width of two classes that you are using in your footer

- social-media
- blog-posts-link

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
   .social-media {
       width: 100%;
    }
   .blog-posts-links {
       width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

Reduce the width to 90% at media screen max-width: 576px;

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
   .social-media {
       width: 90%;
    }
   .blog-posts-links {
       width: 90%;
   }
 }
```

mark as answer if it works thank you ;-)

Comment: DUDE! Thank you! How did you figure that out so fast?! I would never have guessed something in the footer would be the problem...

Comment: It was my pleasure @Rusttune i am glade that it worked happy coding.